# Using a custom script on Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I trying to create a custom script to collect the email filled on field (within my Google Form) and send an email when the user clicks on submit button.

Is it possible do it?

note: I don't want to collect the email address of who's filling the form.. I want just collect the email typed on field and send an email.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts. Question including a brief description of what was tried and description of were the asket got stuck are usually well received. Ref. [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to send the user an email if their email doesn't show up on a Spreadsheet. You're going to have to collect some data in this case, otherwise you won't be able to send them an email.

Use `MailApp` from gScript to send an email. Pretty simple to do with an onSubmit function.

Comment: Hello Andrew,

Sorry, but I found a procedure on: 

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getResponseForItem(Item)

I tried do it and the final result it was as expected... anyway, thanks for your time.